# Android BiometricPrompt throws NPE

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

I'm using `BiometricPrompt` on my app but this code throws `NullPointerException` on some devices (for instance Redmi 5 Plus)

```kotlin
if (biometricManager.canAuthenticate() == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS) {
    biometricPrompt.authenticate(getPromptInfo(), cryptoObject)
}

private fun getPromptInfo(): BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo {
    return BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle("My App's Authentication")
        .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
        .setSubtitle("Please login to get access")
        .setDescription("My App is using Android biometric authentication")
        .build()
}
```

Caused by:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

How can I fix this?

UPDATE (Added logs) :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.biometric.FingerprintDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(FingerprintDialogFragment.java:199)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:419)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1484)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1335)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Comment: Please post code where you are using setVisibility(). that TextView seems to be null

Comment: @Astha It's not a TextView that I'm changing the visibility of. It's somewhere in BiometricPrompt dialog i guess.

Comment: Note that there is a [Jetpack library for Biometric](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric), you may want to see if it resolves the issue, or state clearly which package/version you are using.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I'm using   "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1". The alpha version gives the same exception.

Comment: Not sure if [this AOSP issue ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167951429) is yours but it looks similar.

Comment: @Alvin : Yes you might be changing visibility of Biometric promt, but the crash is coming at android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)'. Please check your crash log for line number and to resolve that null value.

Comment: @Astha According to the stacktrace, the problem is in FingerprintDialogFragment, when it tries to set subtitle. The TextView is null. (Line 197 & 199)

Comment: Oh i see, that's why complete crash logs are important :)

Comment: @Astha Updated the question, addding logs :)

Comment: What is the behavior, when authenticate is invoked by passing null in the second parameter ? i.e, cryptoObject as null

Comment: @Shank Still the same.